# Book recomendation for studying applied Differential Geometry and Topology

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, book-recommendation, applications

What are some good books(or notes in the internet) for (self)studying applied topology and applied differential geometry?

Comment: Ghrist's [*Elementary Applied Topology*](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/notes.html) might be worth a look.

Comment: @pjs36 thanks, i will check it out